# Combinar celdas tomando datos de múltiples celdas

Tags: excel

Últimamente he tratado de unir varios datos que son iguales pero que se diferencian de un solo factor que es la diferencia de horario.

Es decir, tengo una tabla en excel con datos donde tengo mi nombre, asignatura, hora de inicio y hora fin, pero los datos se repiten en el sentido que en hora inicio tengo `7 am` y luego hora final tengo `8 am`, luego en la siguiente celda tengo los mismo datos solo que la horas son de `8am` a `9am` y requiero hacer una sola celda que tenga de `7 am a 9am` (pueden haber más de dos celdas con diferentes datos por decir de `9am a 10 am`).

[image: Objetivo a conseguir al combinar celdas]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes resumir tus datos con una tabla dinámica:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

> [Crear una tabla dinámica para analizar datos de una hoja de
> cálculo](https://support.microsoft.com/es-es/office/crear-una-tabla-din%C3%A1mica-para-analizar-datos-de-una-hoja-de-c%C3%A1lculo-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576)

En mi imagen se ve que mi tabla dinámica ha extraído exactamente la información que quieres.

He usado la siguiente configuración:

1. En FILAS he puesto los campos EMPLEADO y DÍA
2. En VALORES he puesto HORA INICIO, pero lo he configurado para enseñar el valor mínimo
3. En VALORES también he puesto HORA FINAL pero lo he configurado para mostrar el valor máximo.
4. He desactivado SUBTOTALES, TOTALES GENERALES y he aplicado MOSTRAR EN FORMATO TABULAR

Merece la pena que pruebes con tablas dinámicas, y si no sabes, que mires algún tutorial en Internet o algo, porque son bastante fáciles de utilizar, y en este caso hacen exactamente lo que necesites.